# Why am I getting this strange JSON as output?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

My PHP function to handle the AJAX request is

```
 $nameMap = array( 'name' => 'Name', 'email' => 'Email Address', 'phone' => 'Phone Number', 'comments' => 'Comments');
// https://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
function contact ( )
{
    global $nameMap, $headers;
    $emailMsg = '<html><body><h3>Someone submitted a contact form ...</h3><table>';
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) if (array_key_exists($key, $nameMap)) $emailMsg .= '<tr><td><b>' . $nameMap[$key] . ':</b></td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
    $emailMsg .= '</table></body></html>';
    if (mail("barryoabama@whitehouse.com","A Comment Was Submitted",$emailMsg,$headers))
    {
        echo json_encode(array('succeeded' => true, 'msg' => 'Your comment was submitted successfully!'));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('succeeded' => false, 'msg' => 'There was a problem with the info you submitted.'));      
    }
}
```

and my JavaScript is

```
                $('.contact-form .contact-submit-btn').click(function(e){
                    formdata = new FormData($(this).closest('.contact-form')[0]);
                    formdata.append('action', 'contact');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formdata,
                        async: false,
                        success: function (retobj) {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(retobj)); // TEST
                            if (retobj.succeeded)
                            {
                                $('.contact-form h1').text('Your email was submitted successfully!');    
                                $('.contact-form input[type="text"]').hide();                       
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $('.contact-form h1').text('Your email was not submitted successfully!');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function () {
                             // haven't decided what to do yet
                        },
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    });               
                });
```

and when the `else` block of the PHP script is entered (I don't know about the `if` block because I haven't been able to get in there haha) I see

```
"\r\n\r\n0"
```

printed to the console, whereas I expect to see

```
{"succeeded":true,"msg":"There was a problem with the info you submitted."}
```

Where are all those characters coming from? Especially the `0` ... Ever since I started learning PHP, I always get that a `0` added to the end of my callback object.

Comment: so start debugging: litter your code with debug output and see where/when things are getting executed.

Comment: Why do you use `json.stringify`?

Comment: Try replacing the header to `header('Content-Type: application/json');` Edit: Actually, try setting the header, as that header was being used only in the mail.

Comment: You have to *call* functions to make them do anything in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP isn't returning anything.

Try this:
Change the content type to application/json

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

and add this to the very end...

```
echo '{"succeeded":true,"msg":"There was a problem with the info you submitted."}';
```